# why does this redis docker image take so long to come up?

Tags: docker, redis

I am using a fairly vanilla docker image that starts up a cluster of 8 redis servers

https://github.com/pjrt/docker-redis-cluster

However, it can often take as long as a minute for docker to report that the image is healthy, when I use this command

```
healthcheck:
  test: "[ \"$$(redis-cli -p 7000 ping)\" = \"PONG\" ]"
```

If I were to fork and configure the docker image for optimal startup time, what do I need to do?

Comment: have a look at what happens when you launch it, the start.sh file is at https://github.com/pjrt/docker-redis-cluster/blob/master/docker-data/start.sh

Comment: Configuring an 8 node cluster takes a while.